# What if a comment answers a question?

Tags: support, comments

In [„Why does the use of microtype and xfrac lead to a high compile time?“](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27963/why-does-the-use-of-microtype-and-xfrac-lead-to-a-high-compile-time) the comment seems to provide the best answer. If seen this also in other questions. What is the best way to accept it as answer?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The usual approach is to post a comment asking the person who posted the information to convert it to an answer. I'll do that.

Answer (score 21):

I fully support Joseph's answer.

If we do that, sometimes the comment poster doesn't create an answer though, perhaps because he didn't read the request or he doesn't care.

To not let the question unanswered, it would be ok then that anybody writes the solution as answer, after some time and referring to the commentator, which can be accepted then. We often posted such answers in community wiki mode, as nobody earns reputation and other users could easily improve it.

Such examples where I did it:

- [Problem with ntheorem, mathtools and cleveref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15235/problem-with-ntheorem-mathtools-and-cleveref/27392#27392) after about 5 months, during an ["Answer the unanswered" session](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/regular-lets-deal-with-unanswered-questions-chat-meetings)
- [missing file from the package symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25564/missing-file-from-the-package-symbol/27455#27455) after some weeks

Comment: This should be a last resort, though; the original commenter should be given a good amount of time to do the conversion after being asked.

Comment: What about having some moderators who are explicitly on the look for seemingly unanswered questions which have nonetheless been answered in the comments, i.e. moderators who are able to "convert" a comment to an answer? To me it seems as if the number (and ratio) of such seemingly unanswered questions is growing and this is something that really should be avoided.