# A comment sort of answered my question, how do I marked it answered

Tags: support, comments, answers, policy

So I made this question earlier

[pdflatex stuck compiling, gives no error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195480/pdflatex-stuck-compiling-gives-no-error)

and a commenter pointed me towards what could be wrong, I changed my document accordingly and now everything works. I want to mark the question answered.

Should I wait for the commenter to post an answer or should I answer the question and add the changes I made to the document ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related/duplicate: [What if a comment answers a question?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/what-if-a-comment-answers-a-question)

Quite often it happens that the problem is a typo or alike and we consider it off-topic.

However, in this case I would ask **Ian Thompson** to provide an answer, since the question carries information that can be useful to others :)