# Make old question answered

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

There is a bunch of questions that are answered, but not marked so.

Is there a way to remove questions from the "unanswered" lists if they are obviously answered?

One example: [Problem with mhchem subscript and superscript alignement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198132/problem-with-mhchem-subscript-and-superscript-alignement). Here, the last statement from the author is

> Problem solved with an update at home. Thanks.

This question was asked by an unregistered user 6 months ago, with no further actions since, so I doubt, the author will ever mark that questions as answered.

Comment: Related: [What if a comment answers a question?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1731) In this case (a package update), I would (and have) voted to close as off-topic (solved in comments or solved by updating the TeX distribution).

Comment: I have made comments lately asking to post an answer. We got quite a few questions off the unanswered list. Thanks to all answerers.

Comment: @Johannes_B But it doesn't seem so easy to get the attention of some commentors. In https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228704/installing-sty-linux-mint-texlive-not-working I asked a commenter to convert his comments into an answer. This guy is quite active here and I think he surely would do that, but somehow he did not notice my remark.

Comment: @mhchem I wasn't really sure what to answer, and this is definitely a dupe. Well, ... [Installing STY linux mint texlive not working](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235684)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list of [unanswered questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/unanswered) are those "with no upvoted or accepted answers":

[image]

There are a number of ways this is dealt with:

1. The community occasionally hosts an "[Answer the Unanswered](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1560/5764)" event;
2. If [solutions are found in comments](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3640/5764), we ping the relevant parties and request a conversion. If this seems fruitless, some community members may step in and provide a community wiki answer;
3. The network attempts to bring these questions to the community's attention by occasionally pushing content to the [main/active page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/); most notably this is visible when a post appears on the active page, modified by user [Community ♦](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community):

   [image]

If a post can not be address by the above-mentioned methods/suggestions yet still seems solved (perhaps, as you mention, the OP states that it's solved without any idea of how), we may close it, since it doesn't really serve the future community much purpose.

Comment: You may add to the third item, that this effects answered but not upvoted Qs.

Comment: 1. Could you (or someone else) give a time indication? How long should we give the author to convert a comment into an answer? 2. So you don't care so much about the green tick mark, because an upvoted answer removed the question from the unanswered list?