# Upcoming event "Answer the unanswered"

Tags: support, chat, unanswered-questions

In the right column on the "questions" page there is a box "Upcoming events" with an entry "Answer the unanswered in 5 days". Where do I find more information on what this event is about? Clicking on it leads to the chat room "TeX, LaTeX, and friends", which seems to be unrelated and is a bit surprising .

Comment: The `Answer the Unanswered` (or `Upvote the unupvoted answers` ;-) is the monthly event in Chat and on the TeX.SE main site. It usually takes place on the first Saturday of the month.

Comment: Does this event still exist? I don't see the announcement anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a time when active community members felt the number of [unanswered questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/unanswered) was growing too rapidly. Perhaps the community seemed more inclined to focus on a steady stream of new, answerable questions than to worry and/or deal with questions that may be out-of-scope or lack too much detail.

The result was a scheduled time when everyone can join in and collaborate on sorting out the unanswered pool as best they can. From closing questions as being off-topic, unclear what is being asked (if not reproducible or no minimal example to support a claim) or turning comments into answers. "Answer the Unanswered" is this community event, and it's informally hosted within [the regular chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends).

Related:

- [Regular “Let's deal with unanswered questions” chat meetings?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1560/5764)
- [List of "Technology" sites sorted by *percent answered*](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-percentanswered)
- [Things to do on a slow day at TeX-SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/385/5764)

Comment: Also a chance to have a fresh look at entirely answerable but more tricky questions: those are really what I hope get tackled (they are after all where real expertise helps).

Comment: @JosephWright I was wondering about this event as well when i was new here, Maybe we can do something to link to some explanations on what the event is about.