# If the 365-day roomba requirement 'has 1 or 0 comments' were dropped, would valuable contributions be lost?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

The old question [roomba](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) requirements are:

> If the question is more than 365 days old, and ...
>
> has a score of 0 or less, or a score of 1 and a deleted owner
>      has no answers
>      is not locked
>      has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
>      **has 1 or 0 comments**
>      isn't on a meta site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.

We're discussing this idea of dropping this condition on meta.SE:  [Modify the 'has 1 or 0 comments' requirement for 'RemoveAbandonedQuestions' script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322197/modify-the-has-1-or-0-comments-requirement-for-removeabandonedquestions-scri) and [Examples of questions which would be roomba-ed if it weren't for the 'has 1 or 0 comments' requirement, which have important answers in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343683/examples-of-questions-which-would-be-roomba-ed-if-it-werent-for-the-has-1-or-0).

The main concern is that there's valuable information in those comments.  [Marijn indicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343700/351283) that TeX.SE is full of answers in comments, citing [Why do people answer in comments?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments).  Of course, the people with the most informed opinions about this are here.

Hence...

**Question**: If the 365-day roomba requirement 'has 1 or 0 comments' were dropped, would valuable contributions be lost?

---

With [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/revision/1196606/1474020/the-roomba-365-day-rule-what-happens-if-we-drop-the-has-1-or-0-comments-requi) it seems dropping the "has 1 or 0 comments" condition would result in **the deletion of 5271 questions**.  The first three examples from each year are:

2010:

- [Pros and Cons XeTeX vs pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3823)
- [Disabling the colored box surrounding links in hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4871)
- [How do I give an equation a name instead of a number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5112)

2011:

- [Externalize eps figure with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9202)
- [includegraphics - inserting png image leads to blank picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11467)
- [combining existing symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13614)

2012:

- [Creating multiple PDF files from a single LaTeX file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39778)
- [Directly embedded images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40056)
- [how to define a newcommand with several optional arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40132)

2013:

- [What formatting should I use on 'd' when writing an integral?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88909)
- [chapter heading section heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88997)
- [The gaps in a matrix brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89159)

2014:

- [Accent Commands Interpreted as Internal Bibtex Commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152209)
- [Changing bibliography style does not change output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152371)
- [How can I use natbib and make my reference list resemble apalike?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152712)

2015:

- [How to load input file with given starting string but unknown end?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220256)
- [Keeping track of book edits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220302)
- [Line spacing not working with \fontsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220333)

2016:

- [How to refresh citation drop-down list after adding an entry to the current bib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285420)
- [xelatex.exe failed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285508)
- [Compiling a tex file with Texmaker changes the "date modified" meta-information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285530)

2017:

- [How to put this movie (.mp4) in my slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346527)
- [Equation alternative for text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346830)
- [Compilation progress update for TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/347130)

2018:

- [Bibliography is only printing keyword in ArsClassica](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408340)
- [Exam class - customising question numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408380)
- [Two-column book with `mwbk` messes up Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408477)

2019:

- [Is it possible, in theory, to take a file, let's say a pdf, created from a tex source file, and convert it to said tex source file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468177)
- [Import a single letter from a different font (and use it in text mode)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468183)
- [processing part of a document with no output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468195)

Comment: Side note: we don't do [Answer the unanswered](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7166) events anymore, so comment answers are no longer converted into real answers.

Comment: I don't quite know what "locked" means here. Does that include posts closed as duplicates? If the roomba would delete duplicates than that would be a shame since those often help people find what they are looking for. Especially on a lower-volume site like ours losing those would be an issue (and we are more likely to lose even good duplicate signposts because they might not be able to get past the view count barrier).

Comment: I looked at a few of them and they all had mode than 1 comment, so not sure they should be on this list. Furthermore, the ones I looked at were closed as duplicates and I think having duplicates makes it easier to locate actual answers.

Comment: @PeterGrill the new proposal is to automatically delete questions with more than 1 comment, i.e., to remove the comment requirements from the list of auto-delete conditions.

Comment: @Marijn: Oh. Thanks for the clarrification. I don't see why there is a need to delete questions and who benefits from that (except for the minor space savings on the servers)!

Comment: @PeterGrill according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba the reason is that "Abandoned, unanswered questions can be a nuisance for readers when they appear in search results" and therefore such answers should be deleted to clean up the search results. Currently a question is _not_ deleted if it has 2 or more comments. The new proposal is to delete such questions as well. At TeX.SE we would lose useful posts if this proposal is implemented, because we somewhat regularly answer in comments.

Comment: Some sites, like Stack Overflow, have many "meh" questions---they're not of much lasting value, often poorly written, yet are still on-topic.  The authors might shoot off a question unique to their at-the-time interests, and perhaps it gets a few "I don't understand" comments.  A year later, the OP has perhaps forgotten the question even exists.  I believe the idea of deleting these is to raise the overall quality and reduce the uninteresting unanswered questions.  (There's often a claim that they can be re-asked, if they are truly important [yet somehow didn't get upvoted much].)

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones: Ok, that makes sense. IMO, if the question was closed as a duplicate then it should NOT be delteted as that improves the probability of a person finding it in the future.

Comment: Out of interest: Could you modify the SEDE query that excludes duplicate closures (I tried some things myself, but apparently I don't do SQL)? I'd be interested to see how many cases that would leave. As I hinted at before I think that deleting good duplicates would be a shame, but I would like to understand the scale of non-duplicates that would remove.